# How to use vue.data in local vue.directives?

Tags: vue.js

I have this script in the component

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "Auth",
  data() {
    return {
      page: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
  mounted() {
    this.page = 3; //works
  },
  directives: {
    swipe: {
      loaded: {
        function(el, binding) {
          alert(this.page == data.binding.page); //doesen't work
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

But in the chrome i have an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined

So why this  is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive hook can access the component through the `vnode` argument:

```js
export default {
  directives: {
    swipe: {
      inserted(el, binding, vnode) {
        console.log(vnode.context.page)
      }
    }
  }
}
```